# filter search in a array with a wildcard string

Tags: javascript

I have a array of objects.
hope you get the idea with this picture.

[image]

```
getCondition: function(type, processParam) {
    var filter;
    if(type == "description") {
        console.log("_dgnConditions",_dgnConditions);
        filter = _dgnConditions.filter((condition)=>condition.description == 'string' && item.indexOf(processParam) > -1);
    }
    return filter.length ? filter[0] : null;
},
```

Im trying to find string partials in this massive array using the above code, but I get no results.

partial example would be `facial bones` for instance (of the picture)

**EDIT**

```
filter = _dgnConditions.filter((condition)=>condition.description == condition.description.indexOf(processParam) > -1);
```

Comment: `typeof condition.description == 'string'`?

Comment: its type is string your checking or variable itself named with 'string', i think your checking for the type of condition.description ? . then use typeof operator

Comment: also, where is `item` coming from in `item.indexOf(processParam)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:-

```
getCondition: function(type, processParam) {
    var filter;
    if(type == "description") {
        console.log("_dgnConditions",_dgnConditions);
        filter = _dgnConditions.filter((condition)=> typeof condition.description == 'string' && condition.description.indexOf(processParam) > -1);
    }
    return filter.length ? filter[0] : null;
},
```

as `condition.description == 'string'` will not check the type. and you are looking for the index of `processParam` inside the description.

not sure where `item` is coming from.

Comment: Yep. thanks that worked fine. my bad, i used a example and forgot about `item`